# Javascript not decoding string when reading from file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read one local text file in javascript and putting its content in one text area, line which I am reading from file contains encoded value. Below is example file content of file temp_label.txt:

```
{language_tag:zh_CN,value:"\u8f93\u5165\u4e9a\u9a6c\u900a\u63d0\u4f9b\u7684\u5546\u54c1\u7a0e\u52a1\u4ee3\u7801\u3002\u5982\u679c\u4e0d\u8f93\u5165\u4efb\u4f55\u5185\u5bb9\uff0c\u5c06\u9ed8\u8ba4\u4e3a\u514d\u7a0e\u3002"}
```

When I am taking above line in one variable and printing it using console.log() its not decoding string, but when I am putting same line in local variable instead of taking from file, this is getting decoded by console.log()

```
    <html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function readTextFile(file)
    {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                {
                    var strFromFile = rawFile.responseText;
                   console.log(strFromFile); 
                   localStr='{language_tag:zh_CN,value:"\u8f93\u5165\u4e9a\u9a6c\u900a\u63d0\u4f9b\u7684\u5546\u54c1\u7a0e\u52a1\u4ee3\u7801\u3002\u5982\u679c\u4e0d\u8f93\u5165\u4efb\u4f55\u5185\u5bb9\uff0c\u5c06\u9ed8\u8ba4\u4e3a\u514d\u7a0e\u3002"}'
                    console.log(localStr);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }
    function getData() {
      readTextFile("file:///Users/roopjain/Desktop/SCP_Files/temp_label.txt");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="my_button" value="Click here" title="Click here" onclick="getData()"/>
<textarea id="allRows" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the output of both colsole.log()
{language_tag:zh_CN,value:"\u8f93\u5165\u4e9a\u9a6c\u900a\u63d0\u4f9b\u7684\u5546\u54c1\u7a0e\u52a1\u4ee3\u7801\u3002\u5982\u679c\u4e0d\u8f93\u5165\u4efb\u4f55\u5185\u5bb9\uff0c\u5c06\u9ed8\u8ba4\u4e3a\u514d\u7a0e\u3002"}

{language_tag:zh_CN,value:"输入亚马逊提供的商品税务代码。如果不输入任何内容，将默认为免税。"}

Please help me in getting converted value for line which I am reading from file.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is purpose of two `:` characters within property name of object?

Comment: You have to make it a valid JSON, that is `{"language_tag": "zh_CN","value": "..."}` and use `JSON.parse` (or the respective jQuery option) on the client.

Comment: @guest271314 : Sorry I did not get where I kept two `:` , even if I am putting a single char `\u8f93` also, I am facing same issue, so I think its nothing related to string format and content.

Comment: @georg I know its not valid JSON, and as of now I do not worry about that, because data can be anything, my concern is even if I am putting single char (encoded) in file, its not getting converted, but same is converting when taking as local var

Comment: @roopaljain: because it's JSON or Javascript parser that does this conversion and you don't run the file through it.